# Travis fails now Rails 4 has been released

Tags: ruby, rubygems, activesupport, travis-ci, ruby-1.8.7

Here's the relevant part of my gemspec:

```
spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 2.13.0"
spec.add_dependency "addressable"
spec.add_dependency "activesupport", "> 3.0.11"
```

Travis is failing for ruby 1.8.7 because it tries to install ActiveSupport 4.0, but Rails 4 does not support ruby 1.8.7. I'm afraid this might be an issue when users try to use the gem, even though it might be compatible with 1.8.7.

How can I fix this, while also keeping Rails 4 support? I don't want to use `"~> 3.0.11"` on my gemspec.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest altering the contents of your gemspec to something like:

```
  if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"
    spec.add_dependency "activesupport", "~> 3.0.11"
  else
    spec.add_dependency "activesupport", "> 3.0.11"
  end
```

Technically this does use the syntax you don't want, but it does so in a constrained way, and should not adversely impact users. In fact, it *only* affects the build process of the gem, and will make Travis use a restricted version of the dependency (as an end user would have to anyway) without placing *any* constraints on the gem in general - provided you package and release the gem whilst using a more recent Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [`appraisal`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) gem for this. It allows you to generate multiple Gemfiles for the project and then you can specify the gemfiles like this:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
  - 2.0.0
gemfiles:
  - gemfile/3.0.gemfile
  - gemfile/4.0.gemfile
matrix:
  include:
    - rvm: 1.8.7
      gemfile: gemfile/3.0.gemfile
```

This will generate five builds:

- 1.9.3 + 3.0
- 2.0.0 + 3.0
- 1.9.3 + 4.0
- 2.0.0 + 4.0
- 1.8.7 + 3.0

Hope something like this helps.